# Why is following function to find length of linked list returning incorrect value?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, linked-list, static, singly-linked-list

Please identify the mistake in logic.
Why is following function to find length of linked list returning incorrect value?

```
int getCount(struct Node* head){
      
    static int count =0;
    Node* ptr = head;
    
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return count;
    else
    {
        count++;
        getCount(ptr->next);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What incorrect value are you getting? What's the required output and your output?

Answer (score 2):

As your function's signature indicates that it should *return* the number of nodes, the `else` block is problematic: it never returns anything.

Also, you don't really need `count`. It is better practice to use the returned value and add 1 to *that*. The problem with the `static count` is that you can then only get a correct result for one *main*(non-recursive) call of `getCount`. If you call it again for another (or even the same) list, it will not restart at 0, and so it will give incorrect results.

So:

```
int getCount(struct Node* head){
    Node* ptr = head;
    
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return 1 + getCount(ptr->next);
    } 
}
```

Also note also that the variable `ptr` doesn't really serve a purpose. Just go without it:

```
int getCount(struct Node* head){
    if(head==NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + getCount(head->next);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the code in question. can you please check now why it is returning incorrect value?(count is static)

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question. This makes my answer look irrelevant.

Comment: Ok , reverted the change. but can you help me . if I replace "getCount(ptr->next)" with "return getCount(ptr->next)" . this should work as count is static. but its not working. Not able to understand.

Comment: See addition to my answer in second paragraph. With `static count` and `return getCount` it works correctly only the first time.

Comment: Did this answer your question?